# Tkinter progress bar freezes GUI

Tags: python, function, tkinter, thread-safety, progress-bar

I'm trying to run an indeterminate progress bar with Tkinter over python.

I'm using a thread for running some script.py using subprocess, this is the flow:

1. initiate a thread for a function (that includes the subprocess command).
2. start the thread.
3. start the indeterminate progress bar - which is placed on the root.

The progress bar starts moving, but if I minimize the GUI window, and return, it just goes into "not responding" and freezes.

I know that Tkinter is not thread-safe, but I'm sure there is a way to solve this.

here is the code:

```
# Thread start:
  def start(self):
      self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run_command, args=(
                    CTFpath + " " + os.path.join(FWpath, version, FWProductionPath) + " --release",))
      self.thread.start()

# function with subprocess
  def run_command(self, command):
      self.ui.ProgressBarStart()
      self.process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=False, stdout=outfile)
      subprocess.Popen.wait(self.process)

# function to start progressbar
  def ProgressBarStart(self):
      self.progressBar.place(x=430, y=272.4)
      self.progressBar.start()
```

The progressBar was already initialized in the main.
Is there any way this can be fixed?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please provide a runnable [mre].

Comment: @martineau i'm not sure what that means, I have used the minimal reproducible code, I even took more code lines from my code :)

Comment: It means provide enough code (i.e. something complete) that others could run to reproduce the problem, not a few choice snippets.

Comment: @GeorgeHanna Please read the information provided in the link that martineau gave you. If you don't read that page, then "minimal reproducible example" will indeed be meaningless to you. Currently, your code only contains three methods of an undefined class. Could you provide a minimal (uses as few lines of code as possible), reproducible (we can copy and run the code directly from your question, and it will demonstrate the problem) example?

Comment: You could start the progress bar from the main thread just before starting the new thread which runs the script.  You should only touch the gui from main thread.

Comment: @nadapez can we please chat?

Comment: @nadapez i've tried that, it also freezes the GUI, I'm not sure how to fix this I have been trying for a week now.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin Hi, the problem is that the code is so complex, with many files and classes, It's so hard to start taking code and paste it here, I'll need to paste it from lots of places, and check if that's a working code after removing lines.

Comment: @GeorgeHanna I understand the difficulty in reproducing a problem from a large application in a small program, having tried to do it myself ;-)! But you don't necessarily need to copy and paste your code; just create a mini version of your app that demonstrates the same problem. I'm pretty sure that in this case all the extra widgets and functionality aren't necessarily contributing to the problem, so they don't need to be in your example. It may take some work to remove all the unnecessary parts of your app, but it will definitely help us narrow down the problem!

Comment: Before using a progress bar in a GUI, perhaps you should try making a small test program that does nothing else but that — if you run into the same issue, then you'll have the needed [mre].